# preserving image quality J2K/MXF => FFV1/MKV interlaced

Tags: ffmpeg, video

i need to transcode lossless JPEG2000 video to FFV1. the source video is interlaced, but using a non-standard method developed by [opencube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCube_Technologies) that uses 1 field per frame.  i succeed at preserving interlacing (for the most part -- see below), but the quality suffers because the output shows clear interlace lines (the "zig-zags").  this image shows what i mean (source at left, output at right) :
[image]

on the ffmpeg output, i noticed a slight difference in the interlacing as reported by ffmpeg, and i'm not sure whether it's significant.  the input file is labeled as `(pc, top first)`, while the output is `(pc, top coded first (swapped))`.

here are the full lines :

**input video**

`Stream #0:0: Video: jpeg2000, yuv422p10le(pc, top first), 720x288, lossless, SAR 8:15 DAR 4:3, 50 tbr, 50 tbn`

**output video**

`Stream #0:0: Video: ffv1 (FFV1 / 0x31564646), yuv422p10le(pc, top coded first (swapped)), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 1k tbn`

here is my command line :

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i $input \
    -c:v ffv1 -level 3 -threads 8 -slices 16 -slicecrc 1 \
    -color_range jpeg \
    -g 1 -pix_fmt + \
    -vf tinterlace=0 \
    -c:a copy -map 0:v -map 0:a -y $output
```

i've also tried to give ffmpeg some clues by expanding my filter chain with `setfield=tff` and/or `setparams=field_mode=tff`, but that did nothing.

QUESTIONS :

1. what is "top coded first (swapped)" and how is it different to top-field-first ?
2. (most importantly) can someone suggest a way to encode these videos correctly without the interlace lines?

many thanks.

Comment: @RomeoNinov: No, one of the main differences JPEG2000 has from traditional JPEG is that it has an option for lossless compression.